# Set value of select statement into variable and use in update query mysql

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

What I'm trying to achieve is to update a column on the database based on the result of a select query in mysql.

For example:

```
SELECT id, value, t_stamp FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC Limit 1
```

then the value of the SELECT statement say would be

```
id    value    t_stamp

1      apple    2013-01-01

2      dog      2013-01-01
```

so then the value of the SELECT would be from 2 right. but i want to get the value of the 'value' column and use that as a parameter for the UPDATE

```
UPDATE table_name SET newvalue = value_from_select
```

so then value of the newvalue would be dog.

How can I do this in Mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select id,@b:=value,t_stamp from table_name ORDER BY id DESC Limit 1;

UPDATE table_name SET value = @b where id=2;
```

you can use @var:= operator to store the retrieved data in a user defined variable which can later be substituted in an update query as shown above. 
You can also use SET @a = 0 or 0.0 or '' to define its type before retrieving data in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes, almost. I tried doing it like how you said but I had an error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Comment: No I want to do UPDATE table_name SET newvalue = value_from_select WHERE id = 2, sorry i forgot to add the id

Comment: do you want to read the the value of id from the select query as well?

Comment: edited my answer. I had missed a semi-colon earlier which may have been the issue.

Comment: no, i just want to get the value column and use the result of that value column on the update query

Comment: in the above queries you are reading the value 'dog' in a variable 'b' and then setting the row with id =2 with the new value 'dog'. Thing to note here is that value of value is 'dog' already so the update will not bring any visible change.